# R Shiny Render data load only if Tab is selected and dateRangeInput is changed

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simplified R Shiny app below. There are two menu items and two tabs within Menu Item 1.

Tab 2 has a DT Output, which is built off of data which is rendered in a reactive expression.

**Current Behavior:** Data for Tab 2 is rendered via `processed_data` reactive expression every time menu1 and Tab 2 is selected.

**Desired Behavior** I would like the data for Tab 2 to render automatically when menu1 and Tab 1 are selected, but not to render again unless in addition to those two conditions, the further condition that date_range2 is updated from its current value (i.e. if the user leaves Tab 2, then they can go back to the tab without re-rendering the data, unless they decide to change the date range).

I have not been able to figure out a way to accomplish this. The rendering process is computationally expensive for my actual data so I have put an action button in my app requiring the user to click the action button to render the data. However, because I'm restricting the data to a small subset of the data by default, it will load quickly when they go to the tab initially, so I would like it to render automatically rather than require a button click.

The app code is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

generate_dates <- function(start_date, end_date) {
  all_dates <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = "days")
  all_mondays <- all_dates[weekdays(all_dates) == "Monday"]
  return(all_mondays)
}

start_date <- floor_date(as.Date("2023-07-01"), unit = "week", week_start = 1)
end_date <- floor_date(as.Date("2023-12-06"), unit = "week", week_start = 1)
dates <- generate_dates(start_date, end_date)

df <- data.frame(
  Week = dates,
  Value_1 = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), length(dates), replace = TRUE),
  Value_2 = sample(c("X", "Y", "Z", "W"), length(dates), replace = TRUE)
)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    id= "sidebarID",
    conditionalPanel(
      condition="input.sidebarID =='menu1' & input.innerTab=='Tab 1'",
      dateRangeInput("date_range1","Select Tab 1 Date Range",
                     start=max(df$Week),
                     end=max(df$Week),
                     min=max(df$Week),
                     max=max(df$Week),
                     format="yyyy-mm-dd"
                     )
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition="input.sidebarID =='menu1' & input.innerTab=='Tab 2'",
      dateRangeInput("date_range2","Select Tab 2 Date Range",
                     start=max(df$Week),
                     end=max(df$Week),
                     min=max(df$Week),
                     max=max(df$Week),
                     format="yyyy-mm-dd"
      )
    ),
    menuItem("Menu Item 1",tabName="menu1"),
    menuItem("Menu Item 2",tabName="menu2")
  )
)

body<- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName="menu1",
            tabsetPanel(
              id="innerTab",
              tabPanel("Tab 1"),
              tabPanel("Tab 2",
                       DTOutput("myDataTable")
                       )
            )),
    tabItem(tabName="menu2")
  )
)

ui<-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Navigation"),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server<-function(input,output,session){
  
  processed_data <- reactive({
    shiny::req(input$sidebarID =='menu1' & input$innerTab=='Tab 2')
    
    df%>%
      filter(
      Value_1=="A"
    )
  })
  
  
  output$myDataTable <- renderDT({
    datatable(processed_data())
  })
}
  
  

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `eventReactive()` as shown below:

```
processed_data <- eventReactive(input$date_range2, {
    shiny::req(input$sidebarID =='menu1' & input$innerTab=='Tab 2')
    Sys.sleep(3)  ### delay for calculations
    df%>%
      filter(
        Value_1=="A"
      )
  })
```